# How can I brint sox to the forground when using with mimeopen?

Tags: sox

I use the [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) file manager on ubuntu to naviate through my file system.

I want to be able to play any mp3 quickly by just pressing RETURN.

To this end I've used mimeopen to instruct Ubuntu to open all mp3 with [sox](https://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Sox provides the "play" function, so I did:

`mimeopen -d my_audio_file.mp3`

which gave me the following output:

`Please choose a default application for files of type audio/mpeg

```
    1) play  (play-usercreated-2)
    2) Audacity  (audacity)
    3) Kid3-qt  (net.sourceforge.kid3-qt)
    4) Kid3  (net.sourceforge.kid3)
    5) Parole Media Player  (org.xfce.Parole)
    6) VLC media player  (vlc)
    7) LibreOffice  (libreoffice-startcenter)
    8) Other...
```

use application #

...
`
I choose "other" and then "play".

This works great, except for one thing: it opens the mp3 in the background, so I have no direct control over the playback. Ex: I can't pause it. To stop the playback, I have to `killall play`, which is not ideal.

Does anyone know how I could get sox to open it's normal status display, including the ability to hit CTRL-C, when used in the context I've described above?

Thanks in advance!

=======  ======= =======